# moving data from redis standalone instances to redis cluster

Tags: redis

I have multiple redis instances. I made a cluster using different port. Now I want to transfer the data from pre-existing redis instances to the cluster. I know how to transfer data from one instance to the cluster but when the instances are greater than one, I am not able to do it.

Comment: Best strategy that I found was to use redis-trib migrate command. But this will delete the data from standalone redis instance. So you can first create a slave of your redis standalone instance, change its configuration from read only to read-write and then use redis-trib migrate command without loss of any data. Anyway thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

You need to define some sort of sharding strategy for your redis cluster. [Database Sharding](http://www.agildata.com/database-sharding/) So basically you need to have a certain **consistent** hashing strategy which will decide given a key, the shard or the redis instance in your cluster the key will go to. You need to have a certain script for this data migration that will have an array of all the redis instances in your cluster.

Then for a given key which you read from the standalone redis, you will use the hashing mechanism to find out the sharding index or the redis instance from the list you maintained earlier to use and accordingly you will write the data in that cluster node. My assumption in all this is that you have an in house redis cluster setup as opposed to the one which [Redis Labs](https://redislabs.com/) provide.